# How to add scroll with percentage width?

Tags: html, css

I need to add scroll to the div. The problem is that the div in witch is text needs to be in percentage. So if there is a long name i need to scroll it in parent.

[image: scroll]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="list">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/no_camera.jpg">     </div>
        <div class="text_data">Intell. off. ch. 1 with a very very very long</div>
    </div>

    <div class="info">
        <div class="image">
            <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/u/14396564/no_camera.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="text_data">Intell. off.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#list{
    max-height:200px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    padding:5px;
    /*display: none;*/
}

.info{
    border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.info .image{
    width:20%;
    display:inline-block;
    margin-right:20px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}

.info .image img{
    width: 100%;
}

.info .text_data{
    display: inline-block;
    /*border: 1px solid green;*/
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow-x: auto !important; 
}
```

**[jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/nonamez/2DLqq/)**

Comment: What do you want? The fiddle already has a scrollbar, so that's not the problem.

Comment: @MrLister on my screen text is under image, but i need it on side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the text to always appear to the right of the image, without wrapping, you need to set the div's `white-space` property to `nowrap`.

[New jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2DLqq/4/)

So this is the new CSS for `class="info"` (the rest is unchanged).

```
.info{
    border: 1px dashed #CCCCCC;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding:5px;
    overflow: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/2DLqq/3/

**EDIT** (on side of image, vertical scroll): http://jsfiddle.net/2DLqq/6/

**EDIT** (on side of image, horizontal scroll): http://jsfiddle.net/2DLqq/7/

You need to add a container div around .text_data and set the container to overflow-x:auto; and white-space:nowrap; so it's one line of text rather than wrapping to a second line.

```
<div class="text_data_container">
     <div class="text_data">
          Your really, really, really, really, really, really long string of text.
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text_data_container {
     overflow-x:auto;
     width:100%;
}

.text_data {
     display:inline-block;
     white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Also your "vertical-align:top;" in your original .text_data has no effect since it only applies to images.

Comment: yours scroll appears under the image, but i need it in front of image, as in the second div.

Comment: Updated my answer. See the two links, on side of image scrolling (vertical vs horizontal). Your pic shows right side of image but you just mentioned in front of image so by moving the image DIV after the text you should be all set.